# [Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "productInfo"

Tags: vue.js

I'm fairly new to Vue so this may be obvious, but I must be missing something.  I keep getting the error: `[Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "productInfo"` in my .vue file.  It says its found in ProductSlider.vue.

ProductSlider.vue

```
    <template>
  <div
    id="recommendedProducts">
    <h2>{{ params.headerText }}</h2>
    <div
      class="wrapper">
      <div class="carousel-view">
        <carousel
          :navigation-enabled="true"
          :min-swipe-distance="1"
          :per-page="5"
          navigation-next-label="<i class='fas fa-3x fa-angle-right'></i>"
          navigation-prev-label="<i class='fas fa-3x fa-angle-left'></i>">
          <slide
            v-for="product in products"
            :key="product.id">
            <Product
              :id="product.id"
              :product-info="product"/>
          </slide>
        </carousel>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Slider from './Slider'
  import Product from './Product'
  import {mapState, mapGetters} from 'vuex'
  import axios from 'axios';

  export default {
    name: "Slider",
    components: {
      Product
    },
    props: {
      productInfo: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
      }

    },
```

I chopped off the end of the ProductSlider code because the rest is very long and irrelevant.

And then here is my Product.vue:

```
<template>
  <Product>
    <div class="img-container text-center">
      <a
        :href="productInfo.href"
        class="handCursor"
        tabindex="0">
        <img
          v-if="productInfo.imgOverlay"
          :src="productInfo.imgOverlayPath"
          :alt="productInfo.title"
          :aria-label="productInfo.title"
          border="0"
          tabindex="-1">
        <img
          :src="productInfo.imgURL"
          :alt="productInfo.title">
      </a>
    </div>
    <h4 class="itemTitle">{{ productInfo.title }}</h4>
    <div class="price-div">
      <div class="allPriceDescriptionPage">{{ productInfo.price }}</div>
    </div>
    <a
      href="#"
      tabindex="0"
      name="instantadd">
      <div class="btn_CA_Search buttonSearch gradient"> Add to Cart</div>
    </a>
  </Product>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "Product",
    props: {
      productInfo: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

I have `productInfo` in the props so I'm not sure why I keep getting this error.

Comment: I didn't see you use `productInfo` anywhere in the `ProductSlider.vue` component. Do you actually need it in the component? And if you need it, did you pass the prop from the parent component?

Comment: It is used inside the for loop on the `Product` element.

Comment: The `productInfo` is being generated in one of the methods inside the ProductSlider.  It doesn't get passed down from a parent.  But it needs to get passed down to its child, the `Product`.

Comment: In Product.vue, you have <template><Product>...</Product><template>.  This seems unusual.  Could you try <template><div>...</div></template>?

Comment: That's child component's prop which you have already declared in `Product`. Just delete the `productInfo` prop in `ProductSlider`, I think you confused the usage of `props` -

Comment: @JoeZ I have switched `<Product>` to `<div>`.  Didn't solve my error though.

Comment: What I mean is don't declare `ProductInfo` props in `ProductSlider` because it's not used anywhere in the component, at least from the code you gave us.

Comment: Wow!  I removed it and that fixed it!  Now I have just one more question, isn't it used in this code from the ProductSlider? `<Product
              :id="product.id"
              :product-info="product"/>`

Comment: I added an answer to clarify your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you confused `props` and the child component's `props`, when you have:

```
<Product
  :id="product.id"
  :product-info="product"/>
```

You have a prop `productInfo` defined in the child component `Product`, not in the component `ProductSlider` itself, and if you define prop `productInfo` in `ProductSlider`, then you have to pass it down from the parent component, that is you need to have `<ProductSlider :product-info="..."/>` whenever `ProductSlider` is used.

Notice `<Product :product-info="product"/>` doesn't mean you are using the value of `productInfo`, `product-info` is the name of `prop` that's defined in `Product` component.

I think a fair analogy to use is *if you think of your component as a function, `props` are function parameters, and required function parameters need to provided **when they are called***.

For your case, to eliminate the error, you can simply remove the `productInfo` prop from `ProductSlider` component since it's not used in that component.